# What is the latest way to import Sketchup models (Sketchup 2015/2016 free) into a Unity 5.4 2D game without using paid plugins and assets?

Tags: unity-game-engine, import, texture-mapping, sketchup

I have been searching on the net for 8 hours now, and apparently I have not come across any up-to-date helpful information regarding how to import models in Sketchup into Unity **with textures**, using the **free** versions of both pieces of software.

**Method 1: Direct import**

To start with, I tried the most direct way: import Sketchup into Unity 5.4 directly, which they said they support it [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-ImportObjectSketchUp.html).

[image: Direct import from Sketchup 2015 .skp to Unity]

While the texture is a bit difficult to see, in my Sketchup model, a concrete texture is used. In Unity, it is completely grey. I zoomed in very closely in both the scene and the game view to verify that.

[image: Sketchup model]

I am aware that there are a couple of limitations listed in [Unity's documentation regarding Sketchup](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-ImportObjectSketchUp.html), especially the very first one: **GIF textures are not supported**.

My texture is a .jpg of size 512x512. When applied to the standard sphere, it works.

[image: Texture applied to standard sphere]

Another limitation is that Unity is having problem loading Sketchup 2016 files. The problem is described [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/sketchup-2016-import-not-working.373894/) by someone in the community and I have personally experienced the problem. Therefore, I have saved the model as Sketchup 2015 format before importing.

**Method 2: Via Blender**

Next, following instructions on this [link](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-import-a-sketchup-skp-model-into-unity-with-textures.99965/), I gave Blender a try. After exporting a COLLADA file from Sketchup, I imported it in Blender.

Contrary to step 4 in the thread, I am unable to see the texture in texture mode, render mode or material mode.

[image: COLLADA model on display in Blender's texture mode]

Upon export to .fbx in step 5, there is no texture saved in a /Textures/ folder next to the .fbx file.

Then of course, when imported into Unity, there is no texture.

Well, after all, the thread is over 5 years old. I have no idea if this method is still valid.

**Speculation**

Through my long journey on the net, I have read an old piece of information (can't remember where or exactly how old the piece of information is) at various places that COLLADA exported from Sketchup does not have UV information attached.

I knew how to use Blender a couple of years back, but I have forgotten most of it. Ultimately, I might have to re-learn Blender. But time is of essence right now so I have only got a few days left to stuff my models into Unity.

**Question**

Back to my question, what is the latest way to import Sketchup models (Sketchup 2015/2016 free) into Unity 5.4 **without using paid plugins and assets**?

**Question updated**

When I created my project, I set it to be 2D. Further meddling with the Unity editor shows that if I import 3D models (using method 1) into a project that was created in 2D, the texture will have problem displaying.

On the other hand, if imported into a project that was created in 3D, the texture will be fine.

Perhaps there are some 2D settings will prevent the texture to display? To test that, I copied settings from my 2D project and pasted into /<3d-project>/ProjectSettings/. That does not kill the texture.

Are there any other settings somewhere could have caused that?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the texture type from `default` to `sprite (2D or UI)` this tells unity that this texture can be wrapped around a model.